# Mobile Device 6.5 remote sql server connection

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm new to developing smart device applications and ran into a strange issue when trying to connect to a remote SQL Server 2008 Express instance.

The Database is reachable as I can connect to it from my development PC via Management studio.

When I try opening a connection to it from my project I receive a Native Error. I think it is somehow related to my connection string. As you can see I have an SQL Server instance called SQLEXPRESS.

If I remove this from the connection string and only leave "server=192.168.10.2,1433" then I get a normal SQL exception not a native one. However If I use the correct value `(server=192.168.10.2,1433\\SQLEXPRESS)` then the native error comes up.
I'm including a very basic code that throws the mentioned exception.

The problematic line is `myConnection.Open();`

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SmartDeviceProject3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection;
        String constr = "server=192.168.10.2,1433\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=HKTLMSDB; User Id=user; Password=password; Connection Timeout=20";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        GetData();
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            myConnection = new SqlConnection(constr);
            myConnection.Open();
            //some code here that queries data from the server and fills it into a datagrid
            myConnection.Close();             
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

The exception is the following:

> ExceptionCode: 0xc0000005
>
> ExceptionAddress: 0x03fa25e4
>
> Reading: 0x00000000
>
> Faulting module: coredll.dll
>
> Offset: 0x000585e4

at DbNetLib.ConnectionOpenW(IntPtr pConnectionObject, String networkname, Int32& errno)

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I found the reason for this error. The server instance should be separated by slash instead of backslash in the connection string. 
The correct way to do it is: `"server=202.31.95.86,1433/SQLEXPRESS;"`

I used backslash in all my desktop applications without an issue though! It seems the compact framework is a bit more sensitive.